# Ajax request Syntax issue

Tags: json, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Here my code in sencha for receiving JSON data, Problem is when i call is always shows the error message because of syntax.I dont know where it fails coz im new to sencha,Here my code

```
   Ext.Ajax.request({
                     url: 'http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/Login',
                     method: 'POST',
                     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;' },
                     jsonData:{
                               username : "faz@gmail.com",
                               emailId : "faz"
                              },
                     success: function (response) 
                     {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                     },
                     failure: function (response) 
                     {
                     alert(response.responseText);
                     }
                  });
```

When the above method calls it showing the following response

```
  <html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.14 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-
  family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;}
  H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-
  size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-
  color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-
  serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-
  serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-
  serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color :
  black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 404 - </h1><HR   
  size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The requested resource () is not available.</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.14</h3></body></html>
```

I call the JSON url in fiddler as in the following format

```
  Method: POST
  URL:  http://117.218.59.157:8080/WishList/Login
  Request:
  {
  "emailID": "xy@gmail.com",
  "password": "ganesh"
  }
  Response:
  [
   {
    "response": "Success"
    }
   ]
```

I dont know where my code fails .please help me to sort it out

Comment: If the server returns a 404, it has nothing to do with Sencha stuff.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP status 404](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) means "resource not found." The server at 117.218.59.157:8080 isn't configured to serve a resource on the path `/WishList/Login`. You'll have to look at the server configuration/code to figure out why that is. Note that some HTTP servers are case-sensitive, and so (for instance) `WishList` and `Wishlist` may not be the same thing to the server.

Comment: i have cheked its `/WishList/Login` only..And its propely working in a fiddler.Is their any problem with Syntax in `Ext.Ajax.request`

Comment: @ioseve: I'm having trouble believing that the same URL results in a 404 when called via ajax, but not when you retrieve it another way. Of course, that could be server configuration in some way, but it would be a bit non-standard. I could see it if you didn't get a response at all (that would mean you were hitting a [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction), but not that it returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use a google chrome extension to check the services I call via Ajax in order to make sure they are OK. This one helped me a lot you just put your URL in there and mimics the GET/POST -- https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo

Good Luck!